# Setting a part of a PWD as a prompt and keeping a variable updated

Tags: linux, environment-variables, prompt, csh, tcsh

I'm using tcsh, and I'm trying to set a part of the PWD to appear always in the prompt (so I will always know in which "parent" directory I am).

I managed to extract the needed part of the prompt in the following way, and it works fine (I call it `MyTreePath`):

```
set MyTreePath=`echo $PWD | awk '{... print whichTree}'`
```

I've added the code above to my `.tcshrc` and I've added `%$MyTreePath` to my `set prompt` line in `.tcshrc`.

The problem is that once the shell is opened, the `MyTreePath` doesn't change, even if I'm going to a totally different path.

How to keep a variable that appears in the prompt updated?

Comment: Don't use `csh` or `tcsh` ; read [csh considered harmful](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) and switch to a better shell ([zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/) or at least `bash`)

Comment: DO use `tcsh`! As an interactive shell, it is awesome! Yes, everything in the famous "considered harmful" article is true, but mostly applies to scripts. As a rule, I avoid shell scripts altogether. IMO, "shell scripts considered harmful". Interactive tcsh considered awesome.

Comment: please also show your `set prompt` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the magical `cwdcmd` alias!  It is used for defining a command which executes everytime the cwd changes. In your case, you need to updated your variable.

From the manpage:

> The beepcmd, cwdcmd, periodic, precmd, postcmd, and jobcmd Special
>   aliases can be set, respectively, to  execute  commands  when the 
>   shell  wants  to  ring the bell, when the working directory changes,
>   every tperiod minutes, before each prompt, before each command gets
>   executed, after each command gets executed, and when a job is started
>   or is brought into the foreground.

Here's a quick example:

```
alias cwdcmd 'set FOO=`pwd`'
set prompt='%$FOO >>>      '
```

field testing:

```
cd /
/ >>>      cd dev
/dev >>>
```

So all that's left is to replace `pwd` in the alias above with your own command.

For more info and other magic aliases, see [here](http://www.cnr.berkeley.edu/~casterln/tcsh/Special_aliases.html).