# Replacing a fixed part of PWD in a tcsh prompt

Tags: configuration, command-prompt, prompt, tcsh

My prompt is currently displayed like here:

> [Aug-27 14:36] /x/y/z/w/u/v/dir1/dir2/dir3>

What I would like to do is replace the constant partial-path of the current working directory

> /x/y/z/w/u/v

with

> $WORK

so eventually what will be displayed is

> **[Aug-27 14:36] $WORK/dir1/dir2/dir3>**

`/x/y/z/w/t/u` is always the same path from which I usually do my work and for which I have a local variable `$WORK` set (very similar to the home `~` idea).

A straight-forward solution will be most-welcomed as I really don't know much about setting a shell.

Comment: Don't use tcsh. Read [Csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Consider switching to [zsh](http://zsh.org/).

Comment: I will look into that, but currently would like a solution for tcsh

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `tcsh`? You should read it then edit your question about what you have tried. I guess there is no *straightforward* solution (e.g. you need some work to find it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put those lines into `~/.tcshrc`:

```
set WORK='/x/y/z/w/u/v'
set dollar='$'
alias precmd 'printf "%b" "\e[36m"; date +"[%b-%d %H:%M] " | tr -d "\n";  [ `expr "$PWD" : "$WORK*"` -gt 0 ] && printf "%s" "$dollar$PWD" | sed "s|$WORK|WORK|" - || printf "%s" "$PWD"'
set prompt='%#%{\e[0;0m%} '

# The default tcsh ^L binding for screen clearing does not run precmd.
# This one does.
bindkey -s "^L" "clear\n"
```

`precmd` is a command, which is run before a prompt is shown to you. You can use it to customize your prompt using other commands available on your system.

When it comes to colors, you can add them using those special color sequences like `\e[36m` (more details [here](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php)). In the my example I turned on non-bold cyan for the whole prompt by prepending `printf "%b" "\e[36m";` to the definition of `precmd`. You add your own colors this way, just put that a similar `printf` command somewhere in there. I turned off colors (bringing back the default text color of the terminal) by appending *`%{\e[0;0m%}`* to the prompt, end of which happens to be set by the `prompt` variable. I'm using `%{...%}` because this is how you change colors inside when setting the `prompt` variable. So basically you should use `printf "%b" "...";` for the `precmd` alias and `%{...%}` for the `prompt` variable.

---

I used those for reference:

- [Setting a part of a PWD as a prompt and keeping a variable updated (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871994/4694621)
- [Customizing your shell prompt (www.nparikh.org)](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php)
- [Setting the current path in the command prompt in (t)csh (www.unix.com)](http://www.unix.com/answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/32011-setting-current-path-command-prompt-t-csh.html)
- [How to write If-else statement in one line in csh? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33730994/4694621)
- [How to get a list of tcsh shortcuts? (Unix SE)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171479/128489)

Tested on Ubuntu 17.04 with `tcsh --version` returining `tcsh 6.20.00 (Astron) 2016-11-24 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,nd,color,filec`.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect! Only thing I forgot to mention is I'd like to color this using color %{\e[36m%}. I tried a bit but couldn't seem to find the spot for it. Can you please add this to your answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a custom prompt that probably could give you an idea about how to create/improve yours:

```
set COLOR1="%{\e[0;32m%}"
set COLOR2="%{\e[0;33m%}"
set COLOR3="%{\e[0;36m%}"
set COLOR4="%{\e[0;0m%}"
set COLOR5="%{\e[0;33m%}"
set prompt="$COLOR2\[$COLOR3%n@%M$COLOR2\:$COLOR1%~$COLOR2\] [%p %d]\n$COLOR5>$COLOR4 "
set promptchars = "%#"
```

The prompt will be something like:

```
[user@host:/current/dir] [current date]
>
```

Like the `COLOR` variables you could set `WORK`.

Also, this answer could help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871994/1135424